# Angular 4 how to lazy load controller/module js files from S3?

Tags: javascript, angular

I don't have a backend to run angular, just static js/html files in S3, how to lazy load controllers/modules that are stored as static files inside S3?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/master/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Lazy load succeded if you can see 'Hello world' below</h3>
        <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController"></div>
        <script>
            angular.module("LazyLoadTest", ["oc.lazyLoad"])
                .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile) {
                    $ocLazyLoad.load("https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/raw/master/examples/simpleExample/js/testApp.js").then(function() {
                        console.log('loaded!!');
                        var el, elToAppend;
                        elToAppend = $compile('<say-hello to="world"></say-hello>')($scope);
                        el = angular.element('#example');
                        el.append(elToAppend);
                    }, function(e) {
                        console.log('errr');
                        console.error(e);
                    })
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know about [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) but only works for angular 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 4+ has a lazy loading option built into the routes. The Angular.io docs help explain how to accomplish that here.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Keep in mind, Angular 4+ talks about "preloading", which may be the solution you are showing above. That would mean that after the initial load, all of the other modules will be queued up to load as well. You can read up on that here.

https://angular.io/guide/router#preloading-background-loading-of-feature-areas

As far as serving it from an AWS s3 bucket - You can create an angular app using the Angular CLI, then use "ng build --prod" to build dist files, and throw them in the bucket. Then whenever your index file is called it will bootstrap the rest of the Angular 4+ app with lazy loading.

The getting started guide can be found here.

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Thanks waite,in the example the "6.chunk.js" files is just a static file generated by the build tool? or created on the fly by a backend? https://angular.io/generated/images/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules/chunk-arrow.png

Comment: Follow up, with the *build* option (instead of ng serve) and  https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules  managed to get it working

Comment: Awesome, good to hear. If you want faster initial load times you can use the --prod flag with the "build" option as well, I believe that enables AOT compiling.